# Yii: Controller action to handle record creation and updation in same action method

Tags: controller, yii, action

I am unable to chalk out layout of actions in my controller for some basic features. I have a view which provides account's basic information. Account's spans across many fields so users are most likely to do frequent saves. What I have experienced is every time I do a save, a new row is created. actionCreate is called and it simply dumps in the data in table. I am bound to keep the user on the same interface with all data filled in.

From what I have gathered so far, I can not have action parameter for actionCreate method because it fails since it is null for the very first save.

Following the code snippet from my actionCreate controller method:

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Account;
    $accaddress=new AccAddress;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Account'],$_POST['AccAddress']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Account'];

        if($model->save()) //Account data saving

            if (isset($_POST['AccAddress'])){
            //Yii::log('Dumping infomration for multiple models.');
            $accaddress->attributes=$_POST['AccAddress'];
            $accaddress->acc_id=$model->id;


            if ($pataddress->save()){//Account address saving
            }
            //$this->redirect(array('create','id'=>$model->id));
            }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'accaddress'=>$accaddress,
        'tabss'=>$tabarray,
    ));
}
```

Anxiously looking forward to suggestions / comments. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Faisal

Comment: You need to post the code to be able to view what you are doing wrong, but any tutorial on the net will help you at this phase.

Comment: @Pentium, Please have a look, I just added the code.

Comment: where is your model::findByPk() call to load existing records?

Comment: thats what I tried but for every save action, I dont have the ID so I an unable to query. I just had a reply from Joshua, I think I'll try what he is saying....thanks any way for your prompt replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Gii-generated code, which is good. It's a little unclear from your post what exactly is going wrong, but here are some things to check?

Is it an issue with the user-submitted data having something incorrect, and they need to fix it? If so, then you need to work with the [validation rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules).

Are you using the same form to both create and update records? If so, then you need to make sure that you are including ID as a hidden form field somewhere. When you run `$model->attributes=$_POST['Account'];`, the only way it is going to be able to update an already existing record is if ID is one of the fields coming across in `$_POST['Account']`.

Is the issue with the account addresses? For example, are you trying to have several account address models attached to one account? If so, you will need to add logic here to deal with the multiple possible models.

Hopefully one of those helps.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, storing the id in hidden variable makes sense, let me try that and get back....

Comment: If you are using Gii-generated code, make sure to use the Gii-generated views as well, since they work perfectly in tandem.

Comment: I believe the approach you suggested is correct but now I am again moving in circles. I managed to store the Id in hidden variable but on the next submit, it failed to set the Id attribute saying it is "unsafe". If I make it safe, then I dont get the new  record id so that I could then send it to hidden variable. This is kina strange on Yii's part, well, I will resume my working on this in 8-9 hours and then update this thread...meanwhile if you happen to come across anything, do drop a line. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hey Joshua, I got the solution. Check on this link http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36544-controller-action-to-handle-record-creation-and-updation-in-same-action-method/page__gopid__176002#entry176002. couldn't sleep so came back.... All the best and many thanks for your support.